# trying to install windows 10 on an older mac (10.6.8). using ubuntu to make bootable usbs but none seem to work, please help

Tags: iso

have an old macbook pro running version 10.6.8.  using bootcamp it asks for a windows 7 disc only(no windows 10). using ubuntu with netbootin and making a windows 10 iso seems to get the closest to actually working, but it fails during install every time due to sources/install.wim file.  i notice netbootin takes a while during the bootable usb creation at this file.
read that that file is over 4gb so it needs compression. don't know how to do that.  figured netbootin would take care of it.

also tried woeusb and that makes a bootable usb with i guess a uefi partition but during boot, i hold alt to get to the boot options on the mac, and the computer just stops if i select the woeusb usb option until i hit enter again and it just boots the computer normal.

when using etcher the mac doesn't even show an option to boot from usb.
thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, try https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Comment: keeps giving me an error that it can't find the file or not a regular file or a block device file when i use terminal from instructions from that link.  the iso is just on my desktop and i write /Home/Desktop/thefilename.iso .  i'm stumped.  edit: also thanks, didn't know about apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-windows-10-installer-usb-drive-mac

Comment: thank you for your help